# Why is the default font size of UITextField loaded from Nib is too small?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swiftui, textfield

I created a SwiftUI project to test the font sizes of text fields (from SwiftUI, UITextField and UITextField loaded from nib). I noticed that, the default font size of UITextField loaded from nib is not consistent.

I've uploaded the code to the github link.
https://github.com/felixmariaa/TestFontSize

Here's the screenshot showing the default font sizes in SwiftUI - TextField, UITextField and UITextField loaded from nib.

[image: Showing default font sizes of TextField]

Any idea why the font size of UITextField loaded from nib is too small and not consistent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the iOS version you are currently running (on an iPhone 11 Pro Max I assume something like iOS13) **the default font for a programmatically created UITextField** is font family SanFrancisco with size 17.0 (You can change that programmatically when you create an UITextField).

Meanwhile **the default font of an Interface Builder's based UITextField**, currently in Xcode is as well a SanFrancisco but with size 14.0 (you can change that from Interface Builder > Attributes Inspector > Font).

That's just how the tools we use currently behave.

You can find more about what I stated here directly from apple documentation on typography: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/ where you can read about the default font for iOS and Xcode.